# VLookup function solution requested

Tags: vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet which has got all the data. Column A has the staff initials such as AA, SH, SG.This goes down the column. All other columns there are various data such as fees, amount billed etc. The data extends to a number of columns- more than 50!

What i want to do is for every staff initial that we pick it automatically picks up all the data that is in the relevant rows and columns into another sheet which is next to the master sheet. So for each staff initials all the data in the master schedule is copied on another sheet. Is this possible using VLookup.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a Pivot Table?

Answer (score 0):

As [Chenmunka](https://superuser.com/users/247927/chenmunka) wrote, it'd probably be better using a pivot table.

In any case, here's the `VLOOKUP` solution:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$AA$200,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50},0)
```

First you need to select the row of cells you want to copy data in. Then put that formula into first cell of range. Adjust "A2" target, lookup range, and array length (I stopped at 50) to your needs (i.e. delete any column number you do not want to copy).

Formula needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You may now copy down as needed.